# Textures not being applied correctly

Tags: texturing

I am new to Blender and I was following a YouTube Tutorial on modeling a chair in Blender. Im stuck on the textures part, my chair's edges have received the 'texture' of the wood but it's top is plain brown.

A hint to the problem is that I have mirrored the base of my chair, plus I have applied loop cuts and its right **after** the loop cut that the texture starts to appear. These may not be enough details, please ask if you need more of them.

[image]

[image]

Comment: best help would be, if you show us your .blend file

Comment: Sure, i've added one.

Comment: i am not sure...but i cannot see any texture in your file!?

Comment: There **is** a texture, repeated, but its colors are close to each other.